# Delay on div after new picture

Tags: php, javascript, html, delay

ok i have a script which change the image everytime you rate it, and it is working great, but the problem is that people can spam the rating system so i thought it could be possible to do some sort of delay before the div which contains the rating shows up after the new image was set

code to the ratingbar which should be delayed:

```
<div id="button" onclick="changeSrc2()">
<div class="rate_widget" id="<? echo $id;?>">
<div class="star_1 ratings_stars"></div>
<div class="star_2 ratings_stars"></div>
<div class="star_3 ratings_stars"></div>
<div class="star_4 ratings_stars"></div>
<div class="star_5 ratings_stars"></div>
<div class="total_votes">vote data</div>
</div>
</div>
```

code to change the image onclick on the rating bar:

```
$number="1";
$wrongnumber="2";
$random = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY RAND()");
$place="upload/";
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> ';
while($wor = mysql_fetch_array($random))
  {
  $ids=$wor['id'];
  $name = $wor['name'];
  $images = $place . $wor['name'];
  $number=$number + 1;
  $wrongnumber=$wrongnumber + 1;
echo 'function ' . 'changeSrc' . $number . '() '; ?>
{
document.getElementById("rand").src="<? echo $images;?>";
document.getElementById("button").onclick=changeSrc<? echo $wrongnumber;?>;
document.getElementsByClassName('rate_widget')[0].id = <? echo $ids;?>;
}
<?
  }
?> 
</script>
```

and code to display the first images:

```
    /*Display images*/
$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");

while($wor = mysql_fetch_array($r))
{  
    $place="upload/";
    $id=$wor['id'];
    $name = $wor['name'];
    $image = $place . $wor['name'];
    echo '<img id="rand" src="'.$image.'" style="max-height:330px;">';  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `sleep()` functions. It would look like this:

```
<?php
sleep(2);
echo '
 <div id="button" onclick="changeSrc2()">
 <div class="rate_widget" id=' . $id . '">
 <div class="star_1 ratings_stars"></div>
 <div class="star_2 ratings_stars"></div>
 <div class="star_3 ratings_stars"></div>
 <div class="star_4 ratings_stars"></div>
 <div class="star_5 ratings_stars"></div>
 <div class="total_votes">vote data</div>
 </div>
 </div>
';
?>
```